# Tag Wiki review. Help wanted

Tags: discussion, support

I've taken a pass over all of the current tags on this site and provided some wiki for many of those that were without any. Unless I missed one or two, I think every tag now has *something*. For a few, I didn't supply the extended version.

If someone is better at finding recent changes than I am, it might be worth a look to see if my additions can be improved. There were a couple that are a bit sketchy, and some that had inconsistent usage. For the latter I didn't try to write a wiki covering all questions, but considered the majority. This leaves some questions badly tagged, of course.

Comment: [Recent changes](https://data.stackexchange.com/academia/query/1589005/tag-wiki-excerpt-edits?UserId=75368) since the last SEDE refresh - there are some problems right now: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/378546/295232

Comment: Here are some SEDE queries which can be useful for finding edits to tag-wikis - and other tag-related things: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/2496/2022/4/1 (BTW would perhaps the tag ([meta-tag:tags]) be suitable for this question?)

Answer (score 6):

Thanks for the work, this is great!

> If someone is better at finding recent changes than I am, it might be worth a look to see if my additions can be improved.

<s>I couldn't find any way to list the recent changes either.</s> [Here are the recent changes](https://data.stackexchange.com/academia/query/1589005/tag-wiki-excerpt-edits?UserId=75368) since the last SEDE refresh (thanks @Glorfindel). I have not reviewed in detail, but in general, something is better than nothing, and I'm sure your changes were reasonable.

> There were a couple that are a bit sketchy

Agree, we should probably handle "sketchy" tags directly; I would not recommend writing descriptions for them (only because your work would be lost if they end up getting nuked). GoodDeeds made a [nice meta post](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5045) some time ago where a number of bad tags were listed and eventually addressed. Anyone is welcome to make such a post with some suggestions -- or list a few here in the comments and if we get a critical mass, we can compile them into a new post.

> This leaves some questions badly tagged, of course.

Yupp, this illustrates why your work is so important -- there will be fewer bad tags in future now that the tag is well defined. As for the past ones, no big deal, we can fix them as we come across them.

Comment: Starting a list here with some tags that we might want to consider nuking / merging: network-analysis, minority, linkedin, hyperlinks, faculty, instructor

Comment: Linkedin could be made a synonym fro social-media, I'd think.

Comment: Perhaps not too much of a stretch to make hyperlinks a synonym for citations.